# why does if statement send continue to wrong while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

My program keeps jumping back to my second nested while-loop, what i want to do is continue my Third nested while loop. I have tried continue by itself, continue with label "her" as shown below and have also tried without continue statement. Every time the program jumps to the second while loop.

```
while((line = x.readLine()) != null){
            tekst = line.split("\\s+");
            if(tekst[0].equals(".PUNKT")||tekst[0].equals(".KURVE")
                    ||tekst[0].equals(".FLATE")){
                atrib = new String[100];
                a = 0;
                while(line != null){
                    if(line.equals("..NØH ")){
                        int []N = new int[10000];
                        int []Ø = new int[10000];
                        int []H = new int[10000];
                        line = x.readLine();
                        koord = line.split("\\s+");
                        i = 0;
                        her:while(isInteger(koord[0])){
                            System.out.println(koord[2]);
                            N[i] = Integer.parseInt(koord[0]);
                            Ø[i] = Integer.parseInt(koord[1]);
                            H[i] = Integer.parseInt(koord[2]);
                            i++;
                            line = x.readLine();
                            koord = line.split("\\s+");
                            if (koord[0].equals("..NØH ")){
                                line = x.readLine();
                                koord = line.split("\\s+");
                                continue her;
                            }
                            if(koord[0].equals(".PUNKT")||koord[0].equals(".KURVE")
                                    ||koord[0].equals(".FLATE")){
                                midl = line;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: Given that `line` starts with `.PUNKT`, `.KURVE` or `.FLATE`, how would it equal `"..NØH "`?

Comment: Probably a ton of problems in this code. Starting with: most likely you should NOT create these 3 helper arrays **inside** of that while loop. And please : use meaningful names that follow Java naming conventions. N and H are terrible names.

Comment: Beyond that: your real problem is that you wrote overly complex code. Avoid nesting loops like this. Especially avoid labeled break/continue.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is returning to the third loop as the "continue" is meant to do, but the condition `isInteger(koord[0])` will be false for sure, because if `koord[0].equals("..NØH ")` is true then `koord[0]` is not numeric, right?

Comment: The program is reading through a tekst file. By the rules of the formating the "..NØH" signifies that the next line will contain Three coordinates. The format is Norwegian so NØH stands for North, East and Height.

Comment: Didn't know this file format, thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

the if statment excuted only when

```
if(tekst[0].equals(".PUNKT")||tekst[0].equals(".KURVE")
                ||tekst[0].equals(".FLATE"))
```

then how can you use statement

```
line.equals("..NØH ")
```

I think this program will stuck on the while loop

```
while(line != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at these three lines:

```
line = x.readLine();
koord = line.split("\\s+");
if (koord[0].equals("..NØH ")){
```

The condition `koord[0].equals("..NØH ")` will never be true.

- if line contains "..NØH ", then `koord[0]` will be "..NØH" (without a trailing space!)
- if line contains something else then `koord[0]` will be something different

The next if condition in the innermost while loop is also not fulfilled, so the break statement is skipped.

The next test is the condition of the innermost while loop:

```
while(isInteger(koord[0]))
```

Since `line` was "..NØH ", `koord[0]` is not an integer, so this loop is terminated.

And that brings you back to the beginning of the middle while loop.